# Stepped Infinite Square Well

Tags: plotting, polynomials, code-request, code-generation, code

[image: stepped infinite square well]

Here is the link for making the above graph for the [Stepped infinite square well](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExactNumericalSolutionsForTheSteppedInfiniteSquareWell/).

The problem here is, all the eigenfunctions and energy eigenvalues are previously defined. Whereas, I want to use this form of the potential and solve the Schrodinger equation.

```
V[x] = Piecewise[{{\[Infinity], x <= -1}, {0, x <= 0}, {2, {0 < x <= 1}}, {\[Infinity], x >= 1}}]

Plot[V[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 12}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotTheme -> "BoldColor"]
```

The above is my code and it doesn't produce the desired potential.

> **Does anyone know how to define this stepped infinite square well?
> Or how to extract this potential form from the above demonstration?**

Comment: There the exact form of the potential is not defined in a mathematical equation.

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 4):

Having solved the problem with writing the potential, you may use "Eigensystem" to solve this problem (with arbitrary numerical values):

```
Clear["Globals`*"];
v0 = 3;
hb = 1;
m = 1;
V[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < Pi}, {v0, Pi <= x <= 2 Pi}}, Infinity];
op[u_[x_]] := - hb^2/(2 m) u''[x] + V[x] u[x];
{ev, ef} = 
  NDEigensystem[{op[u[x]], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 6];
Plot[{Evaluate[ef + ev], V[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing. I am unable to plot the potential as you have shown here in blue.

Comment: What is the problem ,"V[x]" is a simple function?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the vertical line near 3 is not coming

Comment: I can not reproduce this bug. I have version 13.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04LTS with version 12.0 of Mathematica. Isn't there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: As a hack, you may put the missing line in the epilog. And maybe you want to report this to "support@wolfram.com"

Comment: Adding ``Exclusions -> None`` to the ``Plot`` options solves the problem in *Mathematica12.0*